# C++ and C# for OOP

Tags: c#, c++, oop

As far as programming with the object-orientated paradigm go, which is the better, easier-to-use language, C++ or C#? What are the distinct differences. Oh, and is C# a strict-superset of C or not.

As a side note, are there any other worthwhile paradigms worth looking at other the OO? (That can be used with C++/C#).

Comment: This is very subjective and depends on the task at hand. For general purpose apps a lot of people will probably say C# is easier, but it is darn hard to write kernel mode drivers in C#.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> which is the better,

For what purpose?

> easier-to-use

Depends on your experience. C# is hard for me because I'm fluent enough in C++ so C# limitations make me angry.

> distinct differences

There are many comparisons on the net. The first thing that always comes first to my mind is RAII.

> Oh, and is C# a strict-superset of C or not.

Definitely not. `int main(){}` is the shortest program in C. It's not valid C#.

> As a side note, are there any other worthwhile paradigms worth looking at other the OO?

Yes, RAII, generic programming.

Answer (score 2):

**Better?**

Depends. Do you want low level control over how your program behaves? Then C++ is probably the better choice. If not, then I would say C#

**Easier-to-use**

Definitely C#

**Is C# a strict superset of C?**

Not by far. They share a few syntactical similarities, but that's about it.

**Any other paradigms worth looking at other than OO?**

Functional programming. With 3.5 and 4.0, C# definitely includes some features that blur the line between OO and Functional Programming (but still allow the two to play nicely together in your applications). C++0x will bring some of those features to C++ as well.

Answer (score 1):

> ... easier-to-use language, C++ or C#?

Definitely `C#`.

> Oh, and is C# a strict-superset of C or not.

No way.

> As a side note, are there any other worthwhile paradigms worth looking at other the OO? (That can be used with C++/C#).

[Functional Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming) ([C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx), [C++0x](http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/C++0xFAQ.html#lambda))

Comment: C++0x surely helps, but you can do many interesting thins in C++03, too!

Answer (score 0):

Templates allow for a functional programming approach to C++. You can do computations at compile-time instead that at run time. 
There is a lot of material on this topic, perhaps the two most clear examples are to be found in these two books:

1. [C++ Template Metaprogramming](http://www.boostpro.com/mplbook/)
2. [Modern C++ Design](http://erdani.com/book/main.html)